# sincedb_path /dev/null doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, bigdata

I want that Logstash parses my file when there is no new line into it.

But it doesn't work:

```
[2017-05-09T17:28:07,523][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.file     ] each: new inode: /exports/export4hadoop_FULL.csv: old inode was ["136139751", 0, 64769], new is 
["136139747", 0, 64769]
[2017-05-09T17:28:07,523][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.file     ] :delete for /exports/export4hadoop_FULL.csv, closing file
[2017-05-09T17:28:07,525][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.file     ] _open_file: /exports/export4hadoop_FULL.csv: opening
[2017-05-09T17:28:07,526][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.file     ] /exports/export4hadoop_FULL.csv: sincedb last value 985877, cur size 985877
[2017-05-09T17:28:07,526][DEBUG][logstash.inputs.file     ] /exports/export4hadoop_FULL.csv: sincedb: seeking to 985877
```

My config file:

```
input {
 file {
  path => "/exports/export4hadoop_FULL.csv"
  start_position => "beginning"
  sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
 }
}
```

I didn't found any .sincedb file under home directory. I don't know where is the .sincedb file used by Logstash ..

And I don't understand why it stores a .sincedb, because I specified **sincedb_path => "/dev/null"**

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file(s) used by default for the sincedb_path value is located at;

LOGSTASH_HOME\data\plugins\inputs\file

I suggest you check that folder for any files, delete them and re-run your test.